# SignalR => how to subscribe to an event using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I'm new to SignalR. I have a jQuery code below, which allows to connect to the hub successfully.
Now I need to subscribe to an event, lets just say, `someEvent`. How can I do that? Transport type according to logs: `serverSentEvents`.
By the way, server side code is a black box for me, I have only name of the event...

```
var hub = $.hubConnection("https://someurl/"); 

hub.logging = true;
hub.start()
    .done(function () {        
        console.log(`Connected... Hub id: ${hub.id}`);
        console.log("Transport = " + hub.transport.name);

        console.log(hub);        
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        console.log(`Not connected: ${err}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple common uses cases and examples

#### Handle Server Methods / Remote Procedure Call

If you'd like to listen for the method `addContosoChatMessageToPage`, you can do it like this:

```js
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
```

#### Handle Connection Lifetime Events

If you'd like to listen for a lifecycle event like `starting` or `connectionSlow` you can do it like this:

```js
$.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
    console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
});
```

#### Send Message to server

If you want to post a message back to the server hub, you can do it like this:

```js
var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Wire up Send button to call NewContosoChatMessage on the server.
    $('#newContosoChatMessage').click(function () {
         contosoChatHubProxy.server.newContosoChatMessage($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
         $('#message').val('').focus();
     });
});
```

### Further Reading

Check out the docs on using the [Hub API on the Client in Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) - they're actually quite good

Comment: I've already red that in official website, but it didn't help me:( I was told to subscribe to the event, and nothing more info.

Comment: Hey @Yurii, sorry, as unhelpful as it may seem, without more about what code you're trying to run, it's going to be hard to give anything beyond generic advice.  This is *how* you listen for events *in general* - It's hard to debug your environment without knowing more about the server, etc.  Maybe try running a tutorial to get a single working version *somewhere* and then seeing if that makes anything click for your use case?

Comment: I need to receive a message ```someEvent``` from hub, not send